# Issue with elseif using datetime

Tags: php

I have a small issue. I had help with code displaying a payweek evey two weeks, which works fine, but I'm not sure how to use an elseif to display a div on the given days.

Here is my code:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('2016-01-25');
       $endDate = new DateTime('2016-01-29');

       $curDate = new DateTime('NOW');   
       $curDateFriendly = $curDate->format('F j');         
       $nextDate = $startDate->modify('+2 weeks');
       $nextDateFriendly = $nextDate->format('F j');
       $payDate = $endDate->modify('+2 weeks'); 
       $payDateFriendly =  $payDate->format('F j');                  

       while ($curDate->getTimestamp() > $nextDate->getTimestamp() && $curDate->getTimestamp() < $payDate->getTimestamp()) {
       $nextDate->modify('+2 weeks')->format('F j');
       $payDate->modify('+2 weeks')->format('F j');
```

And here is my elseif I'm trying to use

```
if ( $curDateFriendly >= $nextDateFriendly && $curDateFriendly <= $payDateFriendly ) { echo "Payweek" ; }
```

I added "friendly" format to compare dates, also a hint, my elseif will work but on off days, I don't understand.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to work out whether it is payweek or not, could you not work out whether payweek lands on an `odd` or `even` week number, and then just base payweek of that. Just a musing, haven't tested it thoroughly but logically in my head at the moment it sounds like it might work.

Answer (score 0):

So this is just a musing but since your Pay week is every 2 weeks, that should mean if you started on week 1 your Pay week would always land on an Odd week during the year. (1, 3, 5 ... n) where as if you started on week 2 it should always land on an even week (2, 4, 6 ... n).

So potentially could you calculate whether it is a pay week based of the parity of the current week number?

I.e.

```
function isPayWeek($parity) {
    $parityBool = ($parity == 'even') ? true : false;

    $d = new DateTime();
    $weekNumber = $d->format('W');

    return ($weekNumber % 2 == 0) == $parityBool;   
}
```

This will return true/false dependent on whether you pass in 'even' / something else. As I said in my comment I haven't completely tested it out, but I've used something similar before to work out Sprints, and it appeared to be working for me and your situation sounds similar.

That way you can call the function `isPayWeek('even')` or odd depending on when your pay week lands in an `if statement` and add the `<div/>` in the body of the conditional like so:

```
$html = '';
if (isPayWeek('even')) {
    $html .= '<div>your content</div>';
}
```

I don't know how you build your views, whether you use template engine like twig, etc so it's hard to say exactly how you can display the div.

**Edit2** Outside of that this may help:

Your current conditional evaluates to these two statements (Note: I have used the 'non-friendly' ones because you can directly compare `DateTime` objects)

```
if (2016-02-10 >= 2016-02-22 && 2016-02-10 <= 2016-02-26) {}
```

It isn't executing because of the first branch in your conditional statement, the 10th February is not greater than the 22nd of February. You may want to double check that.

Comment: thanks for your idea, but if I scrap my progress now and start over I think my head will explode. My code works fine I'm just not sure why the dates aren't comparing correctly.

Comment: @Nick Updated my answer with a solution to your problem (or at least what I expect the problem is)

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm comparing my dates post-process because this week is a payweek. How would I make it compare to this week? The 8th and the 12th?